# ErrorException [ Parsing Error ]: syntax error, unexpected '$password' (T_VARIABLE)

Tags: php, parsing

```
    //If the user has submitted the form
    if (!isset($_POST['Submit']) || ($_POST['Submit'] != 'Register')){
        //protect the posted value then store them to variables
        $username=($_POST['username'])
        $password=($_POST['password'])
        //Check if the username or password boxes were not filled in
```

I can't seem to fix this error I am having? ErrorException [ Parsing Error ]: syntax error, unexpected '$password' (T_VARIABLE)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try This

```
//If the user has submitted the form
    if (!isset($_POST['Submit']) && ($_POST['Submit'] != 'Register')){
        //protect the posted value then store them to variables
        $username=($_POST['username']);
        $password=($_POST['password']);
        //Check if the username or password boxes were not filled in
```

Answer (score 1):

You are missing semicolons after your assignments

```
    $username=($_POST['username']);
    $password=($_POST['password']);
```